# WFS GetFeature request blank XML for some FeatureTypes

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geoext, getfeature

I have following URL request to GeoServer. The first request results blank page but the second page results in number of feature count. Why it there blank XML for some FeatureTypes while other gives number of features.

```
http://192.168.70.65:7070/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typename=GisData:sites&version=1.1.0&resultType=results&service=WFS&

http://192.168.70.65:7070/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typename=NCellGisData:sites&version=1.1.0&resultType=hits&service=WFS&
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the results paremeter in quotes? `resultType='results'` or `resultType="results"`

Comment: @R.K. no cote was required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a WFS version 1.1.1, (see the [OGC Web Feature Service page](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs)) so I'm surprised you're getting any results at all; you must specify a valid WFS version in a GetFeature request (it's only in a GetCapabilities request that you can omit it, or get it wrong as part of the the version negotiation).

Your URLs are wrong too because they must also supply the `service=WFS&` key/value pair.

Looking further you have:

`resultType=hits` this means (according to OGC 04-094):

> The value hits indicates that a web feature service should process the
>   GetFeature request and rather than return the entire result set, it
>   should simply indicate the number of feature instance of the requested
>   feature type(s) that satisfy the request. That is that the count
>   should only include instances of feature types specified in the
>   typeName attribute (i.e. GetFeature/Query/@typeName)

and in your other URL you have `resultType=results`which means (according to OGC 04-094):

> The default value results indicates that a web feature service should
>   generate a complete response that contains all the features that
>   satisfy the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://192.168.70.65:7070/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&typename=NameOfLayerWithSchema&version=1.1.0&resultType=hits&filter=(<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>ColumnName</PropertyName><Literal>ColumnValue</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>)
```

I used above syntax.

```
NameOfLayerWithSchema: layer name with schema i.e schema:layername (example GIS:sites)
ColumnName : name of table's column
ColumnValue: is filter text
```