# Get total feature count in WFS service

Tags: python, geoserver, wfs

How can I get total featurecount from a WFS service? I need to download all features, 1000 at a time, so I want to know when to stop (Or can I just keep going until the response is empty?)

I've tried to find something here, but I dont:

https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/wfs?request=GetCapabilities

The service name is: SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences

This is the code I'm using which is working but I need to know when to stop.

```
import os
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService


downloadto = '/home/bera/GIS/csvfiler_paging/'

wfs1 = WebFeatureService(url=r'https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/wfs?', version='1.1.0')
wfs1.timeout=120

for i in range(0,10000,1000): #I need ot replace 10000 with the total feature count
    print(i)
    response = wfs1.getfeature(typename='SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences', maxfeatures=1000, outputFormat='csv', startindex=i)
    outfile=os.path.join(downloadto,'data_{0}.csv'.format(str(i)))
    out=open(outfile, 'wb')
    out.write(response.read())
    out.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never found how to do it in Python with owslib.wfs, therefore i use the GetFeature request of WFS v.1.1.0 with parameter *resulttype=hits* (as in [Only return the NumberOfFeatures in a WFS query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45101/only-return-the-numberoffeatures-in-a-wfs-query)) and the Python library [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

From [WFS GetFeature request blank XML for some FeatureTypes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/216360/2581)

> the value hits indicates that a web feature service should process the
> GetFeature request and rather than return the entire result set, it
> should simply indicate the number of feature instance of the requested
> feature type(s) that satisfy the request.

```
import requests
wfs_url = 'https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/wfs'
layer = 'SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences'
r = requests.get(wfs_url, params={
     'service': 'WFS',
     'version': '1.1',
     'request': 'GetFeature',
     'resultType': 'hits',
     'typename': layer
 })

print(r.content)

b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="25000" timeStamp="2021-08-29T12:28:39.355Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"/>'

from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring
myxml = fromstring(r.content)
print(myxml.attrib)
{'numberOfFeatures': '25000', 'timeStamp': '2021-08-29T12:28:39.355Z', '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd'}
print(myxml.attrib['numberOfFeatures'])
25000
```